# Flutter: check the modal bottom sheet is closed by drag down or by Navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

```dart
showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
      expand: true,
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: ColorPalettes.white,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      isDismissible: true,
      builder: (rootContext) => ManageSavingsPlanSheet(
        argument: ManageSelectArgument(
          iban: widget.argument.iban,
          cashBalance: widget.argument.cashBalance,
          digitalDepotAccountId: widget.argument.digitalDepotAccountId,
          withdrawBalance: widget.argument.withdrawBalance,
          canWithdraw: widget.argument.canWithdraw,
          isPaused: widget.argument.isPaused,
        ),
      ),
    ).then((_) => _getSavingsPlanDetail(context));
```

Can we check the modal bottom sheet is closed by drag down or by `Navigator.pop`?

Because I have a condition when the modal is closed by `Navigator.pop` want to execute API function (`_getSavingsPlanDetail`), but if by drag down is not.

Because for now the `_getSavingsPlanDetail` is always executed.

To create a modal bottom sheet, I use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet

Comment: if the user closed the bottom sheet it will trigger Navigator.pop so consider using a button inside the bottom sheet to save the details, its also a better user experience

Comment: But my question is how to check the modal bottom sheet is closed by the user (drag) or by `Navigator.pop` (from a button inside the modal bottom sheet).

Comment: I'm saying closed by the user (darg) is also using Navigator.pop behind the scenes

Comment: I see, so it's not possible to detect the bottom sheet is closed by `drag down` or by `Navigator.pop` from a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try in this way

```
bool? b = await showCupertinoModalBottomSheet<bool?>(
      expand: true,
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: ColorPalettes.white,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      isDismissible: true,
      builder: (rootContext) => ManageSavingsPlanSheet(
        argument: ManageSelectArgument(
          iban: widget.argument.iban,
          cashBalance: widget.argument.cashBalance,
          digitalDepotAccountId: widget.argument.digitalDepotAccountId,
          withdrawBalance: widget.argument.withdrawBalance,
          canWithdraw: widget.argument.canWithdraw,
          isPaused: widget.argument.isPaused,
        ),
      ),
    );

if(b == true){
// came from Navigator.pop
// can do anything
_getSavingsPlanDetail(context));
}else{
 // came from other way
}
```

> Note: use `Navigator.pop(context, true);` instate of `Navigator.pop(context);`

Comment: yes this work when using `Navigator.pop`, how if using `popUntil`? Because in that can't `return value`;

Comment: in that case, you should use shared_preferences or provider

Comment: ah thanks man, I fix it using shared_preferences for workaround